# How to access config data in .js in Laravel (Not in blade)

Tags: javascript, config

I can access the config data in `.blade` using

```
{{ config('config.variable') }}
```

However, I have no idea how to access the config data in `.js` file. Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

1. Type 1

   You can use the below code to access environment variables in your `.env` in `js`.

   ```
   var name = '{{ env('CONFIG_FILE_NAME')}}';
   console.log(name);
   ```
2. Type 2

   Or else You may inject environment variables into your `webpack.mix.js` script by prefixing the environment variables in your `.env` file with `MIX_`.

   ```
   process.env.MIX_CONFIG_FILE_NAME
   ```

   Please Refer [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix#environment-variables) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript performed on client-side, and .blade.php on server-side. So, you can only write something like

```
<script>
var cfg = {{ config('config.variable') }};
</script>
```

in your .blade.php file to make it accessable from .js files.
Or using method that is mentioned in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix#environment-variables) by providing MIX_ prefix to variables in the .env file.